# Significato di "prammatica" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> In generale, il modo di parlare del vecchio era quello di
>   persona non abituata a farlo, o almeno rimasta in tutto e per tutto
>   all'epoca in cui lo faceva. Continuamente, durante la menoma
>   frase, egli raggrinzava gli occhi con fastidio, come sempre gli paresse di dir troppo o troppo poco, e certi giri di **prammatica** spacciava con una particolare mancanza di convinzione. Dai suoi accenti, infine, traspariva il ché di inconfondibile dovuto alla buona
>   nascita, e una più o men raffinata cultura ottocentesca.

Ho cercato il termine "prammatica" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono sicura di averne capito il senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Significa "consuetudine"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esatto, significa consuetudine. Il termine indica nel linguaggio giuridico

> leggi (o editti o decreti) di emanazione regia su determinati oggetti,
>   per es. in materia costituzionale, o tendenti a regolare comportamenti
>   pubblici (come, in Toscana, le leggi suntuarie)

Nel contesto da te citato viene usato per estensione per indicare una regola pratica o consuetudine di comportamento.

Da Treccani per [prammatica](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prammatica/)

> 2. Per estens., regola pratica che si segue per consuetudine in determinate circostanze della vita sociale: *una bella corrida, in
>      questa patria dell’etichetta, è ... una prammatica di riti e di gesti
>      e di precetti minuziosi e severi regolati come un duello* (Ojetti). Con
>      questo sign., è di uso com. soltanto nella locuz. *di prammatica*: *ho
>      dovuto ascoltare i soliti discorsi di p. in queste situazioni; mi ha
>      negato il permesso, come di p.*, com’è sua consuetudine; u*n tempo al
>      Teatro dell’Opera era di p. l’abito da sera*.